# how to get running balance from dart list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a table having columns id,debit,credit. I am fetching data from database and generating a list with the help of model. I want to calculate running balance from dart list which should be like this

| Debit | Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 | 200 |
| 100 | 0 | 100 |
| 100 | 0 | 0 |

```
void main() {
      List<LedgerModel> ledgerList;
      int? previousBalance = 2000;
      ledgerList = <LedgerModel>[
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 0, credit: 100),
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 50, credit: 0),
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 250, credit: 0),
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 0, credit: 250),
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 0, credit: 1300),
        LedgerModel(id: 1,debit: 1000, credit: 0),
      ];
      
      ledgerList.forEach((element) {
        print("${element.id}   ${element.debit}   ${element.credit} ${(previousBalance+element.credit)-element.ebit}");
      });
      
    }
    
    class LedgerModel {
      int? id;
      int? debit;
      int? credit;
      
      LedgerModel({this.id,this.debit, this.credit});
    }
```

Comment: I can't directly understand what your problem is. Do you know how to calculate or write the code?

Comment: I have a List<LedgerModel>. I want to calculate and print the running balance while using forEach loop as shown in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the value in **previousBalance** variable so that you can achieve the result like you expected

```
void main() {
  List<LedgerModel> ledgerList;
  int previousBalance = 2000;
  ledgerList = <LedgerModel>[
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 100),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 50, credit: 0),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 250, credit: 0),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 250),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 1300),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 1000, credit: 0),
  ];

  ledgerList.forEach((element) {
    previousBalance =
        previousBalance + element.credit - element.debit;
    print(
        "${element.id}   ${element.debit}   ${element.credit} $previousBalance");
  });
}

class LedgerModel {
  int id;
  int debit;
  int credit;

  LedgerModel({required this.id, required this.debit, required this.credit});
}
```

Comment: Since you change the `LedgerModels` properties to be non-nullable, you can omit the `!` operator to access the class properties. Also the `toInt()` call is unnecessary.

Comment: @quoci You are correct, I forget to remove that. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `credit` and substract the `debit` from your `previousBalance`.

```
void main() {
  List<LedgerModel> ledgerList;
  int previousBalance = 2000;
  ledgerList = <LedgerModel>[
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 100),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 50, credit: 0),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 250, credit: 0),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 250),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 1300),
    LedgerModel(id: 1, debit: 1000, credit: 0),
  ];

  ledgerList.forEach((element) {
    previousBalance -= element.debit ?? 0;
    previousBalance += element.credit ?? 0;
    print(
        "id: ${element.id}, debit: ${element.debit}, credit: ${element.credit}, balance: $previousBalance");
  });
}
```

This will print

```
id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 100, balance: 2100
id: 1, debit: 50, credit: 0, balance: 2050
id: 1, debit: 250, credit: 0, balance: 1800
id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 250, balance: 2050
id: 1, debit: 0, credit: 1300, balance: 3350
id: 1, debit: 1000, credit: 0, balance: 2350
```